# ASP.NET custom routing and friendly URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, friendly-url

I have a website (ASP.NET WebForms) where I build the routing table from the database. Additionally, I have the `friendlyUrl` enabled.

In the `Application_Start` of the `Global.asax` I have the following code:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Clear();

foreach (var page in pages)
{
    Route siteRoute = new Route(page.RouteName, 
        new CustomRouteHandler("~/" + page.Handler));

    RouteTable.Routes.Add(siteRoute);
}

var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
RouteTable.Routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

The RouteTable will be like the following:

#### Friendly URL

```
/default => /default.aspx
/blog    => /blog.aspx
/about   => /about.aspx
```

#### Custom URL from the database

```
/blog/my-first-post  => /blogpost.aspx
/blog/my-second-post => /blogpost.aspx
```

The problem I'm having is that if there is a page named  `www.mysite.com/blog.aspx` for example, and then I put a blog post in the route `www.mysite.com/blog/my-first-post`, the last one is not displayed as the request is sent to the page `blog.aspx` instead of `blogpost.aspx` as I've defined in the previous code (`page.Handler`) in the line:

```
Route siteRoute = new Route(page.RouteName, new CustomRouteHandler("~/" + page.Handler));
```

Is there a way I can work around it and have both URLs, `/blog` and `/blog/my-first-post`, redirected to two different pages?